# MVC3 Downloading individual files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file, download

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  We have an "Attachment" feature.  The user uploads a document they want to "Attach" to a Proposal.  This document is stored on our server waiting to be downloaded.  This part is working.

The user then clicks on the name of the "Attachment" that is displayed as a Hyperlink in a table.  I'm sure there is a common way to do this.  I just don't know how.  How do I download a file using a hyperlink?

Comment: Could you give us an idea as to what the file structure looks like (Where are you storing the files?)? Also, do you store the file name or something in the database?

Comment: @Crowder....the filename is stored in the db, and the file path is a setting in web.config.  We append the filename to the path and have a fully qualified doc path

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To download a file using a hyperlink, you first need to have your action link pass the file name as a route value to the action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", 
                 new { fileName = Model.AttachmentFileName })
```

Your action will take in `fileName`, open it for reading under `/some/path`, and return it using ASP.NET MVC's built in `FileStreamResult`:

```
public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("/some/path/" + fileName));
        return File(fs, "application/zip", fileName);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "Couldn't find " + fileName);
    }
}
```

The `application/zip` parameter is the MIME type of what you're returning. In this case it's a .zip file.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) is a list of possible MIME types.

Comment: @Lester..that looks great...I'llgive it a rip.  Thanks!

Comment: @Lester...In looking for a reference for File.OpenRead, the object browser suggests System.IO.File.  However, the System.IO in my VS2010 does not contain a File class.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code. It should be `System.IO.File.OpenRead()` and it is part of [.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx).

Comment: This won't compile because of this line System.IO.Server.MapPath says it does not have server in system.IO

Comment: @Goldentp thanks for catching that. it's actually part of the base Controller class.

Comment: @Lester Sure but What do I need to add to fix the error then?

Comment: I've updated the code and changed `System.IO.Server.MapPath` to `Server.MapPath` since it's part of the base controller class. If you're still having problems post a question.